# Grub problem with list

Tags: grub2

I have problem with my grub after upgrading ubuntu.
I have backtrack, ubuntu, windows
My problem is that it does show: ubuntu 3.4 kernel and supposedly should be ubuntu 12.04 but it is is loading the backtrack.
I guess grub is messed up.

How i can access the list that is generated by grub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in /etc/grub.d are the config files of grub but they require some programming knowledge to edit them, which I can't provide you, but the tool I use when I get in trouble with grub2 is Grub Customizer wich can help you editing your Grub. You can found it here:

https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

Answer (score 1):

You have two grub2s as boot loaders. Whichever is in MBR is the one used to boot. Which are you using Ubuntu's or Backtracks? The first in the menu is the one in the MBR that you use to boot.
If Booting with Backtrack, you may just need to run this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you want Ubuntu's grub to be in charge or installed to MBR you can boot into Ubuntu and just install its grub to the MBR. If drive is sda:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

But then any updates in Backtrack would need the update-grub to refresh the menu in Ubuntu.